# Lazy loading list box, in a panorama page

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, lazy-loading

I wanted to add a lazy loading list box(load content when swipe) in a panorama page in one of my windows phone 7 applications. I could however do it using a pivot page. I referred [this link](http://danielvaughan.orpius.com/post/Scroll-Based-Data-Loading-in-Windows-Phone-7.aspx)

But this is not working with panorama page.
 Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, you're going to need to do one of two things: use the BCL Async package (basically adds async Tasks and such to WP7) or use a background worker. I *highly* suggest the BCL Async package, it's easy to get on Nuget.

Now, in your ViewModel (you are using MVVM, yes?) the property that it's bound to, let's call it `Items` should return an `ObservableCollection` of the item type you need. Now, here's where the magic happens. In the `Get`ter of that property, return a new collection and use a task to fill it. Something like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<object> Items
{
    get
    {
        ObservableCollection<object> retCollection = new ObservableCollection<object>();
        FillCollection(retCollection);
        return retCollection;
    }
}

public async void FillCollection(ObservableCollection<object> collectionToFill)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        foreach(object objectToAdd in collectionImGettingThisDataFrom)
        {
            // We do this using the Dispatcher to 
            // be sure to pop back into the UI thread.
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                () => collectionToFill.Add(objectToAdd));
        }
    }
}
```

Because FillCollection is async, the Get method will continue and return the current collection. On another thread, the Task that's created will find the data to add, then push it to the UI thread to add it into the collection. This way, you'll be able to lazy load the data only when you ask for it, without completely blocking your UI thread. If it turns out that it's still making your UI slow, you can add the line:

```
await TaskEx.Delay(25); // Some time in milliseconds. Too much and it will 
                        // take a long time to load the list,
                        // too little and it will still bog down your UI.
```

At the end of the `foreach` block, but *not in the `Dispatcher` invokation*.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the Telerik Rad Controls yet? They have all types of pull to refresh controls. I used them in a recent app I released called "Rad Libs". You can see the controls here http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone.aspx and you can also download an app that demos all of their controls. (Disclaimer: I have no affiliation with telerik. I stand to gain nothing from promoting them here)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've heard of it. But i would prefer an alternative way.

Comment: I would suggest at very least downloading the trial, it's free. You can download it and open up the source. You can see how they do it and then maybe replicate it.

Comment: That sounds like it could run into some copyright issues. I'd probably avoid doing that.

Comment: @NateDiamond First off, it would be theft of intellectual property. Second, if you look at code and then write your own that is not IP theft. Third, that is why they publish the code. So you can look at how it works and emulate it or make it better.

Comment: Really? I figured they publish it so that people can do security and performance reviews before purchasing. 100-1500$ (the one hundred being *just* for WP alone) is no laughing matter for some developers, even security-conscious ones.

Comment: @NateDiamond Even if that is their reason, you are still wrong. There is absolutely nothing illegal about looking at someones code and then attempting to replicate it. I didn't say copy and paste it (which obviously would be illegal) I said replicate it. Which means you look at it, then attempt to make your own. If what you say is true then this entire site is one big walking IP theft case...

Comment: @AMR Except that there are generally Fair Use clauses (based on where you happen to come from) that cover things like publicly posted code, such as in blogs or forums, unless otherwise stated such as with a with a note that "All posted code is available via the XXX license", such as Apache, MIT, etc. While Telerik will likely not go after him, developers should still be careful, as it does open them up to possible litigation, such as if a given control looks or acts quite similarly and they can show that the code was viewed. Like, through a posting on this site.

Comment: @NateDiamond Yes, you are correct, fair use. EXCEPT WHEN YOU ARE RE-WRITING THE CODE..... I am sorry that you aren't able to comprehend this but when you look at something, then re-write it, it is yours.

Comment: I just want to clarify that it's unlikely that Telerik would do anything without plenty of cause and plenty to gain (such as if Manoj's code happens to be used by a large corporation, in a place with strong copyright laws etc, etc). It's still something to be mindful of when looking at other's code not specifically stated as reusable, even if chances are that nothing will come of it.